# oracle GTT Vs IN clause literals

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Have a one query , where GTT(few 100 Recs) inner joined with main table.

```
ex :
insert into table1 select col2,col3 from gtt,maintable where gtt.id=maintable.id    .. few other joins
```

The query takes around 15-20min to load to table1, but when i pass those GTT tables value hardcode in query it will completed in 4-5min.

what could be the main difference here, is there any way i can improve performance using GTT.( cannot avoid GTT becuase sometime values may be more then 1000)

Tried below 
1. removed inner join and replace with IN clause ( where IN ( select id from GTT), but no luck
2. added push_subq and unnest HINT with subquery(option 1)  , but no luck

PLAN

```
with GTT

|  74 | NESTED LOOPS                      |                           
|  75 |  BUFFER SORT                      |                           
|  76 |   PX RECEIVE                      |                           
|  77 |    PX SEND BROADCAST              | :TQ20006                  
|  78 |     SORT UNIQUE                   |                           
|  79 |      PX RECEIVE                   |                           
|  80 |       PX SEND HASH                | :TQ20005                  
|  81 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR          |                           
|  82 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | STAGE_GTT    
|  83 |  PX PARTITION HASH ITERATOR       |                           
|  84 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL       | EXP_TABLE                 =====>103GB == cell offloaded 95%  




With literal 

 129 |  PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ20006              
 130 |   HASH JOIN                            |                       
 131 |    PX PARTITION HASH INLIST            |                       
 132 |     VIEW                               |                       
 133 |      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | EXP_TABLE       ====(27GB ) ==cell offloaded 98%
```

Comment: Are columns involved in JOIN indexed?

Comment: Would you mind providing complete query and describe the tables along with Indexes and constraints. Also how many records are in maintable. If you can show sample of data that will be great too.

Comment: @ Littlefoot,  yes It has index , Both GTT and main table ,  however main table index is not used but partition is on the same column.

Comment: @VN'sCorner,     GTT=250 Records, maintable=few million , after GTT and main table join =4777100, query is too  big and complex to past here.   GTT has one index  but we are doing Full table scan, and Main table has few index but again we are doing FTS , but the join is on the partition key column

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just a shot in the dark.If you could respond to my comments can improvise.

```
insert into table1 select col2,col3 from gtt 
        where exists (select 1 from maintable 
                      where gtt.id=maintable.id    
                      .. few other joins)
```

Assumption : col2,col3 are from gtt.

Comment: I tried : insert into table2 select col2,col3 from Maintable where id  in (select id from GTT) , but did not help ,

Comment: My assumption is wrong then. col2,col3 cannot be from GTT as the records returned is 4777100.  They should be from maintable as there are no other tables in the join.

Comment: I believe 4-5 minutes you mentioned is when passed as literal for single value of "id" which is used in the join. How long it takes when you just run select * from maintable? If you are using an editor,its the time taken untill you scroll till the last records.Could you check this please?

Comment: can't run select *from main table. its a partitioned table and has millions of records.

Comment: got it , would you mind in sharing the table structure, at least the columns involved in the join as well as partition.

Comment: MAIN Table(paritioned) 100+ column : 
INDEX_COLUMN_NAME: id  : nouniq  ( index also paritioned)
paritioned on : id
=================================
GTT : 
INDEX_COLUMN_NAME: id  : uniq 
no partition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212889/discussion-between-laks-and-vnscorner).